# Spring 3.5 Setting an xml property, handling the default value using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Tags: java, spring

I'm working with an old project using Spring 3.5 and xml config.

In the application context I am setting a property to an externally configured xml file value so something like this -

```
<bean id="myService" class="com.mypath.MyService">
    <property name="myProperty" value="${myValue}:myDefaultValue" />
</bean>
```

This all works properly.

In some tests though there is a test-context.xml coming into play which sets the values of the properties like this

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties">
        <util:properties>
            <prop key="myProperty">myValue</prop>
        </util:properties>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is failing to 'understand' the default value.  If I leave the value blank I get :myDefaultValue returned.  If I set myValue like my example shows I get myValue:myDefaultValue.

I had a quick peak at the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and it looks very basic without many options.  I've not used it before.  Does anyone know if there is a simple way for me to handle the defaults ?  Or maybe I have to use a different method to set the test context values ?

Comment: IIRC, that should be `${myValue:defaultValue}`.

Comment: what a plank.  Yes and that solves the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure the way forward.  If you like put that as an answer as you've solved it.  Otherwise I'll delete the question and pretend it never happened...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your syntax slightly off. The default value for the expression goes inside the braces, like so: `${myValue:defaultValue}`.

Comment: FYI, it's not SpEL; it's a property placeholder. SpEL is `Spring Expression Language` and is denoted by `#{...}` in XML configuration (rather than `${...}` for property placeholders).

Comment: @GaryRussell My understanding was that the full SpEL engine was available for substitution; is that incorrect? (I've used, for example, string pasting.)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean; I was just clarifying that `${...}` is not SpEL in XML bean definitions.

Comment: @GaryRussell Is it SpEL in `@Value`?

Comment: Not with `${...}`; again you need `#{...}` for a SpEL expression (`${...}` is simple property value substitution). SpEL is much more sophisticated than that; e.g. `#{@someBean.someProperty + @someOtherBean.otherProperty}`.